# Non-consecutive list of cells in a function (rank)

Tags: excel, function

This may be a simple "It's not possible" answer but I want to make sure. I am using LibreOffice at the moment but if it is possible in Excel I can switch.

I have a spreadsheet with a few tables, each with results of the same test on different data. I want to rank the results over all the data in another table (again of the same form).

So, I would like to use the function rank as follows

```
=RANK(B4,{B4,B12,B20,B28,B36,B44,B52,B60,B68,B76,B84,B92,B100})
```

Where the bit in {..} denotes my cell list. In the case of performing getting the sum or average I can do:

```
=AVERAGE(B4,B12,B20,B28,B36,B44,B52,B60,B68,B76,B84,B92,B100)
```

and it works fine. Also, if the cells were consecutive, we can do the following:

```
=RANK(B4, B4:B100)
```

But unfortunately they aren't in this case, so I am wondering whether there is an nice solution to this - other than referencing the cells somewhere else in a consecutive list and using that for input to the rank function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No worries, Ptay.  In Excel, the rank and average functions can be used exactly as you describe (just with parenthesis, not brackets).

Answer (score 3):

In OpenOffice and LibreOffice the symbol ~ is used to connect noncontiguous cells in a numberlist.  So:
    `=RANK(B4;B4~B12~B20~B28~B36~B44~B52~B60~B68~B76~B84~B92~B100)`

Comment: Is it that I can't find it or is there really no LibreOffice Community in Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to avoid linking to another group of consecutive cells you could use a named range then reference the named range in your formula.

Comment: I recommend this especially if you are referencing the same subset of cells often.

Comment: An example would be useful, as I don't understand what you mean, and may not be the only one.